# Should I wrap all my express server in a class with typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I consider myself  enough competent with nodeJs. I have recently decided to change my applications by starting to develop with Typescript. I have recently seen many blogs ([like this one](https://itnext.io/building-restful-web-apis-with-node-js-express-mongodb-and-typescript-part-1-2-195bdaf129cf)) that when creating a RESTful API, they wrapped all the modules and above all the entry point of the app in a class. Is it correct or can I continue to develop my apps with typescript as I had before?

Comment: Consider providing the code you're talking about in the question. The question should be understandable without visiting offsite links. Links can go offline.

Comment: @estus you're absolutely right, but I found it difficult to find examples to explain what I mean

Comment: Vanilla Express basically doesn't need classes, it's pretty much barebone. But you can check NestJS (it is based on Express) for some ideas how Express can fit OOP design.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a matter of style rather than anything else. But Express doesn't promote OOP for its units and there are no distinct benefits from defining an app as a class:

```
class App {

    public app: express.Application;

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.config();        
    }

    private config(): void{
        // support application/json type post data
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json());

        //support application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    }

}

export default new App().app;
```

`App` is a singleton that isn't supposed to be reused. It doesn't provide any benefits that classes are known for like reusability or testability. This is unnecessarily complicated version of:

```
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

export default app;
```

Comment: @Niccolòcaselli As for Express, you just don't need OOP there. OOP is just a way to do things, not the only way and necessarily the best way. Classes are first-class citizens in Typescript because of how how types work there, but it's unnecessary to use them.

Comment: I do not agree. As for most of the cases it is unnecessary, there are some case in which it would be very useful especially for test cases, where You want to test the API by constructing the app first and then starting server (two distinct operations), maybe with different settings then for production/dev. Especially useful when it involves more complicated and async code.

Comment: @DominikMyszkowski As long as you're aware of the the goal, the same thing can be written with functions and plain objects and be more straightforward to use with Express, that's the point.

Comment: Of course it can. But sometimes it is more convenient and readible when put in a class. I have a case for example, where I initialize express app, httpServer and ApolloServer all interdependent in an async function (and also database manager). It is much more convenient for me to put that into class and separate the methods which execute specific code. It is very useful during testing the API with Jest later as I can create the App object and call specific functions. But I agree that in most cases it is unnecessary work which can provide confusion.

Comment: The readability is a matter of taste, I don't think that the habit is enough to justify the choice of a programming paradigm. I mean that the methods be rewritten as a module or several with function exports for the same purpose and wouldn't lose anything except the complexity of code. A class has benefits in Jest because it allows for automocking and also to spy on a proto prior to instantiation which would be harder or impossible otherwise, but I'm not sure it's the case here.